# Change time of Apache log rotation on Ubuntu

Tags: apache, apache2

I am using Apache2 on Ubuntu 20.04. The access.log and error.log files are automatically rotated every day at midnight UTC. How do I change the time so that it, for example, rotates at 11:00 UTC?

This is the default config (/etc/logrotate.d/apache2), which I have not touched:

```
/var/log/apache2/*.log {
        daily
        missingok
        rotate 14
        compress
        delaycompress
        notifempty
        create 640 root adm
        sharedscripts
        postrotate
                if invoke-rc.d apache2 status > /dev/null 2>&1; then \
                    invoke-rc.d apache2 reload > /dev/null 2>&1; \
                fi;
        endscript
        prerotate
                if [ -d /etc/logrotate.d/httpd-prerotate ]; then \
                        run-parts /etc/logrotate.d/httpd-prerotate; \
                fi; \
        endscript
}
```

FYI, the reason I want to do this is that the rotation's associated graceful restart can sometimes cause an "Unable to connect to WSGI daemon process" issue, which is only solved by my doing a regular restart. Eventually, I'd like to solve that, but for now it's OK if I can just make sure that it happens at a more convenient time for me and my users.

Answer (score 0):

You can:

- move out of the logrotate folder (/etc/logrotate.d) the apache2 rotation file
- duplicate the /etc/logrotate.conf file and make sure the "include" options points to a folder containing the apache log rotation file
- create a new entry in crontab to execute the new logrotate config file at the time you wish (crontab syntax: https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crontab)

Another options would be:

- [not required but suggested] change the path where apache stores logs
- append date in the file name using a custom log format (something like 'CustomLog "|bin/rotatelogs -l /var/logs/logfile.%Y.%m.%d 86400" common')
- [optionally] run a cronjob that compress the logs whose name doesn't match the pattern used in the CustomLog

Comment: Do you know what's causing it to be run at midnight currently?

Comment: It's scheduled as a cron job so cron is responsible for its executions.
Cron is a daemon that launches jobs at fixed time (daily, hourly, weekly, etc): you can use it to run your scripts too.
In your specific case, the job is probably scheduled daily so cron launches it when a new day starts.